# Not getting the object key value using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to read some key-value from one object using Javascript but one key value is not reading at all. I am explaining my code below.

```
customer={
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e21bdb921a1de5a8885c368"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "GroupName" : "ashok",
    "CustomerId" : "7008980097Saikantassss@okedqart",
    "GroupCode" : "ashokgrp",
    "GroupType" : "Group",
    "GroupDescription" : "test description",
    "GroupImage" : "",
    "StoreCode" : "DKWF",
    "GroupID" : "1673e78b-8d35-4c5b-9bda-35d8788a64ad",
    "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-17T13:59:21.373Z"),
    "UpdatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-17T13:59:21.373Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here I have the above fetched value from mongodb but when I am printing the customerId value like below.

console.log(customer['CustomerId']);

//undefined

The above value is coming `undefined` but same time `console.log(customer['GroupCode']);` giving the value as `ashokgrp`. Here I need to print also customer['CustomerId'] value.

Comment: As posted, the above works.  Make sure you're spelling `CustomerId` correctly as it appears in your object.  Also confirm that the object has a `CustomerId` field (you can do this by examining the output of `console.log(customer)`).

Comment: I tried the code you posted and i was able to print the value in console using console.log(customer["CustomerId"]). So it should work.

Comment: Seems the problem is how you're fetching values from MongoDB (async issue). Post please how you perform query execution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var customer={
        "_id" : "5e21bdb921a1de5a8885c368",
        "IsActive" : true,
        "GroupName" : "ashok",
        "CustomerId" : "7008980097Saikantassss@okedqart",
        "GroupCode" : "ashokgrp",
        "GroupType" : "Group",
        "GroupDescription" : "test description",
        "GroupImage" : "",
        "StoreCode" : "DKWF",
        "GroupID" : "1673e78b-8d35-4c5b-9bda-35d8788a64ad",
        "CreatedAt" : "2020-01-17T13:59:21.373Z",
        "UpdatedAt" : "2020-01-17T13:59:21.373Z",
        "__v" : 0
    }

    console.log(customer.CustomerId);
```

It Will work .

Comment: You haven't changed anything other than the notation to access the `CustomerId` field (both notations are correct).  If you did make a change, make sure to explain what you did.